# Does permutation test require iid?

Tags: independence, permutation-test, iid

Suppose I have a treatment group X and independent from control group Y.

The data set x1,x2...,   y1,y2... Let's say I want to test the mean of the difference

If the randomization unit is a session and the analytics unit is event level:
which is the data set x1,x2...,   y1,y2... are all collected from each event.

So x1...xn are not independent as part of they might come from the same session so as y1.....yn

So for a parametric test like the t-test, estimate the variance is a problem, we might need some tricks to estimate the variance.

can we use the permutation test here? as during the permutation, we don't need to estimate the variance. Does it violate some assumptions? If not, How could we do it?

Comment: For a two-sample permutation test, the assumption is that the two samples are independent, possibly from different populations. For a paired permutation test, the assumption is that pairs $(x_i, y_i)$ are from independent subjects, sessions, or days, etc. // I wish you had given a clearer, more detailed explanation of the possible relationships among $x_i$ and $y_j.$

Comment: Strictly, you need exchangeability under the null (which you sould get if you have independence along with the usual assumptions otherwise), but the distinction between that and independence might not help you out. I echo Bruce's wish for more clarity to give us some notion of how these values are related.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks. Here as I mentioned we have a randomization unit in session. each session has some events. The data collected is from event level.  In this case the treatment and control independence is hold. but for data in side each group, the data x1,x2.... xn is not independent so as y1....yn.

Comment: TO be clear. we randomize sessions to treatment X and control group Y. Lets say There are n sessions in treatment and n in control. Let Xij denote jth event from ith session in treatment. Yij denote jth event from ith session in control. So the two group data we collected are:  x11,x21.... x12,x22......    x1n...xmn.   y11,y21,....., y12,y22....., y1n,y2n....ysn.